# Java SWT TableViewer. Only allow Entry as DropTarget

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt

I recently added Drag and Drop to my SWT TableViewer. That works well. 
I am able to drag one Element from the source TableViewer to the target TableViewer and I can work with that.

Now comes my problem. I only want to be able to drag an element on another element. In other words I only want to be able to drop my element on another element and **not in between two rows**.

In the picture you can see what I mean. When dragging between two rows the bold line shows up. And I dont want that to happen. It should only highlight rows and the bold line should never appear.

Currently I'm working with `validateDrop(...)` so the drop doesn't work when I release there, but that's not a clean solution.

I hope you can help me.

Drag and Drop Example:

[image: Drag and Drop Example]

Comment: Could you add some code to help understand root cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a drop target listener that extends `ViewerDropAdapter` override `determineLocation` and always return `LOCATION_ON`:

```
@Override
protected int determineLocation(DropTargetEvent event)
{
  return LOCATION_ON;
}
```

Comment: That's it. Thx a lot :)